# Toggle between Layers in QGIS Layer Panel

Tags: qgis, layers

Working on city mapping...
We've several layers that are constantly being edited and saved.

Would like to be able to save a few clicks by creating a custom macro/hotkey to "save current layer", and scroll up or down to the next layer in the Layers Panel.

Thinking "ctrl+mouse wheel up or down".

So far have been unable to find anything of this sort.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any QGIS functionality that can do this but if you are using a Windows machine, I know of two macro applications that can do it:

- Macro Express is a proprietary macro application for automating tasks. It has a powerful GUI-based macro editor so you can pick through and configure commands without knowing anything about scripting. It has a free trial version but it'll cost $45 - $70 for the licensed version. http://www.macros.com/download.htm
- AutoIt is an open source automation app that can do many of the same things but you'll need to learn some scripting to work with it. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

The task you described seems pretty basic so I don't think it would be tough to create a script and configure a shortcut key in either program that would do it.